# Automotive ISO 7637-2 transients and LT4363 surge protector chip

Tags: automotive, surge-protection, transient-suppression

Can [this part](https://ro.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/4363fb-2955353.pdf) be used for the +150V / -220V transients in the ISO?

Taking this diagram:

[image]

And modifying it to this:

[image]

Where the IXFP60N25X3M is a 250V capable N_MOSFET and R_sns = 5 mohm for 10A max.
Any reasons for this not to work ?

Comment: The answer is in the specification sheet. If it is not then choose something else,

Answer (score 1):

Yes if it properly protected.
Right on the VIN (12V),just after the PCB connector or input, place one of the bidirectional [SMA6TY](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sma6t36cay.pdf) TVS with the correct voltage (bidir ends with CAY).
To select the right breakdown voltage, take the maximum voltage between the following voltages:

- Max operating voltage (at which temperature)
- If jump start applicable (ISO 16750-2), the VBR must be higher than 24V
- Centralized load dump voltage (usually around 35V)

For the max operating voltage it is important to correct the VBR value given at 25°C of the Table 2 (page 2) with the formula of Note 1 (page 2)

Most of the time SMA6T36CAY or SMA6T39CAY can fit all the previous requirements for a 12V electrical systems.

In the datasheet you have the response to pulse 3a (-220V) and 3b (+150V) for example
[image: ISO 7637-2 pulse 3a 3b SMA6TY series]

On top of pulse 3a and 3b you will survive pulse 1, pulse 2a, 30 kV ESD (ISO 10605)

I can see that the Linear device can withstand 100V on the VCC according to the AMR. So the clamping voltage of the SMA6TY even with a high VBR should protect it.

You may not need the SMAJ58CA-TR in that case.

Comment: Not sure how a 0.6 kW TVS could survive the first 1ms of a load dump event.

Comment: Actually, as I said, with a VBR higher than the voltage of the centralized load dump, the TVS will not enter in conduction mode. As most of the IC are 40V tolerant they won't be damaged.